# Backbone .fetch() clean data rewriting

Tags: javascript, url, backbone.js, fetch-api

I'd like to make a clean request with backbone on a `fetch` call. My API's URL is `/users/`, and I want to pass data :

```
var users = new UsersCollection({ users_id: "1|2|3" });
users.fetch({
        data: "users_id=1|2|3"
    });
```

Users is a collection of `UserModel`.

But the url becomes `/users/?users_id=1|2|3` but I want it to be `/users/1|2|3`.

I've a `.htaccess` with the following line `RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /api.php?fct=$1 [L]`

How can I do it ?

Comment: Dp you try this `users.fetch({ url: "/users/1|2|3" })`;

Comment: Backbone calls the jQuery method `$.ajax({ url: url, type: "GET", data: "users_id=1|2|3"})` that always appends the data parameter as a query string. If you want a custom url, you should change the `url` parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that using query params for specifying which models the REST api should ask for is better than the "1|2|3" syntax, but if the specifications is to generate a /users/1|2|3 url it can be achieved like this:

```
var UsersCollection =  Backbone.Collection.extend({
  initialize: function(models, options){
    this.requestedModelsId = options.modelsId;
  },
  url: function(){
    return "/users/" +  this.requestedModelsId.join("|"); //generates  /users/1|2|3 if for requestedModelsId [1,2,3]
  }
});


var users = new UsersCollection(undefined, {modelsId : [1,2,3]});
users.fetch();
```

This way the responsibility is left for the collection to know what to fetch for and how to fetch it.